# MUI popover's prop transformOrigin is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popover

There is a button which opens a popover when clicked. The popover contains table. transformOrigin prop of popover is not working. In initial reload, the popover shows in correct position.(Also when I resize window while popover is opened, it again shifts to correct position)[image]

But after popover is close and opened again, it moves to the undesired position(even outside the screen due to position of button).
[image]

Here is the code for button component. Also contains popover

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Popover from "@mui/material/Popover";
import { useState } from "react";
import ChooseRacesPanel from "./ChooseRacesPanel";

export default function ChooseRacesBtn({ date, setIndex }) {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    return (
        <div>
            <Button sx={{ m: 2 }} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
                Choose Races
            </Button>
            <Popover
                open={open}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                onClose={handleClose}
                anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "right",
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: "top",
                    horizontal: "right",
                }}
            >
                <ChooseRacesPanel date={date} setIndex={setIndex} />
            </Popover>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is the table component(ChooseRacesPanel), used inside popover:

```
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ChooseRacesPanel({ date, setIndex }) {
    const [meetingNames, setMeetingNames] = useState([]);
    const [meetingsRaces, setMeetingsRaces] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:3000/meeting/${date}`,
                {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                }
            );
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(json);
            setMeetingNames(json.meetingNames);
            setMeetingsRaces(json.meetingRaces);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [date]);
    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>
                    {meetingNames.map((mName, index) => (
                        <TableRow
                            key={index}
                            sx={{
                                "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
                                    border: 0,
                                },
                            }}
                        >
                            <TableCell align="center">{mName}</TableCell>
                            {meetingsRaces[index].map((race, i) => (
                                <TableCell key={i} align="center" onClick={() => setIndex(parseInt(race.index))}>
                                    <NavLink
                                        to={race.link}
                                        style={({ isActive }) => ({
                                            color: isActive ? '#fff' : '#545e6f',
                                            background: isActive ? '#ee9154' : '#f0f0f0',
                                          })}
                                    >
                                        {race.time}
                                    </NavLink>
                                </TableCell>
                            ))}
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced the problematic case in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-problematic-case-ptovcg?file=/src/ChooseRacesPanel.js).

The problem is related to the change in width of your component after it is rendered inside `Popover`. Popover should be rerendered after the table data is retrieved in `useEffect` in `ChooseRacesPanel` component.

In order to do that, either:

1. You can move `fetchData` to the `ChooseRacesBtn` component (or even further) and pass `meetingNames` down to the `ChooseRacesPanel` all the way down.
2. You can call a callback function from `ChooseRacesPanel` and update the state of `ChooseRacesBtn` by calling this callback function after the data is fetched like this:

`ChooseRacesPanel.js`:

```
export default function ChooseRacesPanel({ date, setIndex, onItemsRetrieved }) {
    const [meetingNames, setMeetingNames] = useState([]);
    const [meetingsRaces, setMeetingsRaces] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:3000/meeting/${date}`,
                {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                }
            );
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(json);
            setMeetingNames(json.meetingNames);
            setMeetingsRaces(json.meetingRaces);
            onItemsRetrieved(); // this is callback after fetch
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [date]);


export default function ChooseRacesBtn({ date, setIndex }) {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
    const [itemsRetrieved, setItemsRetrieved] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setItemsRetrieved(false);
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const onItemsRetrieved = () => {
        setItemsRetrieved(true);
    };

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    return (
        <div>
            <Button sx={{ m: 2 }} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
                Choose Races
            </Button>
            <Popover
                open={open}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                onClose={handleClose}
                anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "right",
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: "top",
                    horizontal: "right",
                }}
            >
                <ChooseRacesPanel date={date} setIndex={setIndex} itemsRetrieved={itemsRetrieved}
                    onItemsRetrieved={onItemsRetrieved} />
            </Popover>
        </div>
    );
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-problematic-case-solution-p2xk28?file=/src/App.js) for a live working example of the second alternative solution.